# Efficiently Concatenating Delimited Characters Into Words

Tags: c#, string

I am working on an NLP based application that uses global keyboard hook to read key presses. Here is it's working interface:

```
BIEngine.Hook.KeyboardListener KListener = new BIEngine.Hook.KeyboardListener();
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    KListener.KeyDown += new BIEngine.Hook.RawKeyEventHandler(KListener_KeyDown);
}
void KListener_KeyDown(object sender, BIEngine.Hook.RawKeyEventArgs args)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(args.ToString());
}
```

Now I am getting the words for the user as space, carriage return, tab, periods etc delimited set of alphabets. So if the user types in his software window `got today` I would be getting

```
g
o
t

t..
```

So what would be the most efficient way (as this application would be running constantly in the background) to concatenate these letters to form words sans the spaces and other delimiters and react to a certain set words, say for example if the user types `today`, it will be passed to the NLP library and the user would be presented with some sort of feedback.
Thanks for any suggestions, codes etc.

Comment: [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) anyone?

Comment: @ZoharPeled is it efficient enough?

Comment: It's probably the most efficient way to do it, at least to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend that you use the simplest approach that does what you want, and stop worrying about performance. Premature optimization, as it's known, can cost lots of time with very little benefit.

If you never let the string get particularly long (like, ~2000 characters) then I suggest you simply append to a normal `string`, trimming it whenever it grows longer than, say, 100 chars. I highly doubt you will be able to observe any performance impact from this. Only if you ever run into measurable performance problems (say, you notice the program taking more than 0.1% CPU time while the user is typing) should you consider optimizing this. And I bet you'll find that it's not your string concatenation that is using the CPU, but something else altogether.

Why? Because if you try to optimize everything before it is a problem, you will never get much actual work done. Most of the time optimization is unnecessary.

Having said all this, the most efficient way to match a string character by character would be to use a finite state machine, but I feel that explaining how to go about that is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: I am acquainted with automata theory and finite state machines and undoubtedly they would perform fastest. However I wanted to know if there is any .net based trick etc for faster performance, however it seems your explanation is really what I needed. I wouldn't even matter at all perhaps. Thanks for the thoughtful input.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your post, I automatically thought about using a write instead of a writeline, but I don't know what implications that might have on your actual configuration.

That would keep it on the "same line", but to what end?

You can also insert a block code to your app to perform the visual or logical transformations, then display it or process it.
This way, you don't have to add additional workloads to your app start procedure.